# How to calculate the distance between the barriers in a double barrier heterostructure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-tunneling

I know there is a peak in the current flowing through the heterostructure when the voltage bias applied $U$ equals 0.05 V. From what I know this should align with the energy being equal to that of the ground state in the well. How would I then determine the distance between the barriers (or the width of the well between the barriers). I was thinking of using
$$
\tan\Big(\sqrt{2mb^2(E+V)/\hbar^2} \Big)=\sqrt{(-E)/(E+V)},
$$

where $m$ is the electron mass, $2b$ is the width of the well, $E$ is the energy and $V$ is the potential. By solving for the width you get:

$$
2b=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{m(E+V)}}\arctan \Big( \sqrt{(-E)/(E+V)}\Big),
$$

I think.

Here I am asuming that $V = 0.1$ eV before a voltage bias is applied.

But I don't know any good expression for $E$ in this equation.

Thanks.